# Bifurcation diagram of a difference equation

Tags: dynamic, difference-equations

The function is

```
f[x_, a_] := Piecewise[{{x (1 + a - a*x), x <= 1/2}, {x (1 - a + a*x), x > 1/2}}]
```

How to make the bifurcation graphic of it?
What information may I take from the diagram?

Comment: We need an equation not a function. Is this a difference equation or differential equation?

Comment: Ok the difference equation the following: x_{n+1}=f(x_n,a)

Comment: What are the ranges of $ x $ and $ a $?

Answer (score 5):

In general you need a DE or a recurrence relation to generate a bifurcation diagram.  For example, the logistic map is:

```
x[n+1]=r x[n](1-x[n])
```

Check logistic map at Mathworld: [Logistic map](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/LogisticMap.html)

Here is code to generate the bifurcation diagram for the logistic map:

```
  ListPlot[Table[
  Map[{r, #} &, 
   DeleteDuplicates[
    SetPrecision[
     Take[RecurrenceTable[{x[n + 1] == r x[n] (1 - x[n]), 
        x[1] == 0.6}, x, {n, 1, 100}], -20], 5]]], {r, 1, 4, 
   0.001}], PlotStyle -> Black]
```

[image: logistic map]

Comment: One up for using `RecurrenceTable` :)

Answer (score 5):

This is my answer after guessing the ranges of $ x $ and $ a $:

```
data = Flatten[Thread /@ 
               ParallelTable[
                             {a, DeleteDuplicates[Chop@FixedPoint[x \[Function] f[x, a], #, 1000] & /@ Subdivide[0., 1., 100]]}, 
                             {a, 0, 2, .001}
                            ], 
               1];
```

where, to speed up the calculation, I use the parallel version of `Table`. One can further make it faster by defining a compiled version of `f` using `Compile`, I suppose.

Then make the figure:

```
ListPlot[data, PlotTheme -> {"Scientific", "SansLabels", "LargeLabels"}, FrameLabel -> {"a", "x"}, PlotStyle -> {Blue, PointSize[.0002]}]
```

[image]