# Bifurcation diagram with two parameters

Tags: plotting, nonlinear, difference-equations

I have a question. In [Bifurcation diagram of a difference equation](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202771/bifurcation-diagram-of-a-difference-equation?rq=1) I asked for one parameter. And now I am going to tell how do I make a bifurcation diagram of that function with two parameters? I have learned how I plotted the bifurcation diagram with one parameter. But I cannot find any information the case with two parameters:

```
f[x_, a_, b_] := Piecewise[{
    {x (1 + a - a*x), x <= 1/2},
    {x (1 - b + b*x), x > 1/2}
}]
```

where $a, b \in [0, 1]$.

Comment: You have already asked this and got answers: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/202771/bifurcation-diagram-of-a-difference-equation

Comment: Yes, you are right. But in general, I have Two parameters. That's why I asked again

Comment: Usually, when you have a closely related question and few answers to the original, it is better practice to leave comments on the answers asking them to generalize, then edit the new information into the question.

Comment: Since there are two parameters, it seems like a 3D plot is required. I don't know if it'll look good, given that a 2D bifurcation diagram is already dense in information.

Comment: Ok can you give me any 3D plot for some DE?

Comment: @lirtosiast on the other hand, moving the goalpost after you get answers is very annoying ([Discussion here](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1808/10397)). This questions should link to the previous question, acknowledge the similarities and **state clearly what is the difference**. Otherwise should be closed as duplicate.

Comment: I am sorry. I am new here. Next time I remember it.

Comment: @JavohirUsmonov, no need to be sorry, no need to wait for the next time. Just [edit] your question now and fix the problem.

Comment: What should I do?

Comment: Click on the [edit] link under your question. Add the necessary context, explain that you have asked this before, and link to your old question. State clearly what is different in this new question. What you need now that was not part of the other question. Share minimal working example of code in formatted form. (@lirtosiast already helped you with this, follow their example)

Comment: That's a very intriguing question.  We can resort to ListPointPlot3D:  Generate a bifurcation diagram Table for f(x,a) for a range of k like Table[getDiagram(k),{k,k1,k2}] (in 3D so will need to store points like {f,a,k}).  This then makes a table of bifurcation diagrams.  then do a ListPointPlot3D for the table.

Comment: What do you want plotted on this bifurcation diagram?  People often plot some qualitative behavior (equilibrium vs two-cycle vs four-cycle, etc.) as a function of the two parameters.